# Using if/else on parent array element for iterations in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I'm posting my full script for relevance.

I'm currently iterating through an array from a JSON object and applying content to an html div based on the content's ID. This works fine but my issue is in the logic based on the parent array in order to hide all unnecessary DIVs. The array looks like:

[image]

My array has a parent element with pageID and pageType and contains a 'Content' array with the actual content. I'm iterating through the content to apply it but I want to be able to, upon each iteration, say "If the parent pageType is n, hide x divs" like this part of the snippet:

```
if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 1){            
      //Some stuff
}else if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 2){            
      //Some stuff
}
```

SO my content is filling properly and the iterations are appropriate, but how can I set the proper divs to hide based on the parent pageType on each iteration?

```js
const obj = [{
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "86",
    "panel_type_id": "2",
    "cont_id": "138",
    "contID": "138",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nLeft 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  },
  {
    "pageID": "93",
    "page_type_id": "2",
    "display_id": "2",
    "slide_order": null,
    "duration": "74",
    "background_img": "images\/bg_rainbow.svg",
    "panel_id": "87",
    "panel_type_id": "3",
    "cont_id": "139",
    "contID": "139",
    "content": "\r\n\r\n\r\n<\/head>\r\n\r\nRight 93<\/p>\r\n<\/body>\r\n<\/html>"
  }
];

let counter = 0;

const pages_array = obj.reduce(function(pages_array, item, index, obj) {
const current_pageID = item.pageID;
const current_pageType = item.page_type_id;
const exisiting_page = pages_array.find(page => page.pageID === current_pageID);

if (exisiting_page === undefined) {
  const new_Page = {
    pageID: current_pageID,
    pageType: current_pageType,
    content: [item]
  }
  pages_array.push(new_Page);
} else {
  exisiting_page.content.push(item)
}

return pages_array;
}, []);

setInterval(()=>{
const currentJSONobject = pages_array[counter]; 

   for(var i = 0; i < currentJSONobject.content.length; i++){            

        if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 1){
            //Some stuff
        }else if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 2){
            //Some stuff
        }else if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 3){
            //Some stuff
        }else if(currentJSONobject.page_type_id == 4){
            //Some stuff
        }
    }

    console.log(pages_array[counter])

    counter += 1; 
    if (counter === pages_array.length){
        counter = 0; 
    }
}, 3500)     

console.log(obj);
console.log(pages_array);
```

Comment: I've added an answer.

Comment: Ok I've tried this but when I add that, then the first iteration of the content is all that shows. After the next iteration it remains blank

Comment: My snippet has the entire object. If you look in the console you'll see that it sets the initial array with pageID and pageType, then the children make up the content array

Comment: I mean the parent object

Comment: the pages_array constant creates that. The JSON i posted above is all I have, I then group by pageID and make the content an array within. I've posted everything I have in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is right evaluation:

```
if(parseInt(pages_array[counter].pageType) == 1){
    console.log("Paren pageType => ", pages_array[counter].pageType);
}
```

Your problem was that you were looking the property `page_type_id` in the`currentJSONobject` instead of looking in the parent object which is in `pages_array[counter]`

Comment: See that's where I'm confused: This answer  prints the correct pageType in the console but my content remains blank after the first iteration. If i remove the entire block of if statements it prints all the content but then I'm not hiding the extra divs

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nf5jLt38/  with the if statements commented out everything prints per iteration as it should

Comment: You'are hiding the same div's when `pageType` is `1 and 2`. Theses are the divs you are hiding in both cases: `leftColumnQtrHalf, rightColumnQtr, rightColumnQtrHalf, leftColumnQtr`

Comment: Which is fine, but in this case when it goes from ```pageType``` 2 to 1 none of those divs should be used. with pageType 1, it should be displaying the content in ```fullColumn```

Comment: Wait a second, when page type 2 hides fullColumn, I would have to 'un-hide' it for page type 1

Comment: Ok I see now. I think I need to set the appropriate divs to 'block' in their own statements

Comment: If the answer help, does not forget to mark it as useful. @Whisou138